# Retrieving entity from repository results in null reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, dbcontext

I am storing something in a repository and need to retrieve the value before calling `SaveChanges`. The result is `null` but in the debugger I can see that the repository contains the local value.

```
var tenant = TenantRepository.Create(model.TenantName);

// a bit further in the stacktrace I retrieve the entity

var tenant = TenantRepository.GetTenantByName(tenantName);
// now tenant is null.
```

---

The relevant methods in `TenantRepository`:

The `Create` method:

```
    public Tenant Create(string tenantName)
    {
        var tenant = new Tenant
            {
                Name = tenantName,
                Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };

        if (Exists(tenant.Name))
        {
            throw new TenantAlreadyExistsException(tenant.Name);
        }

        _repository.Add(tenant);

        return tenant;
    }
```

The `GetTenantByName` method:

```
    public Tenant GetTenantByName(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("name");
        }

        var foundTenant = GetTenants().SingleOrDefault(tenant => name.Equals(tenant.Name));

        return foundTenant;
    }

    private IQueryable<Tenant> GetTenants()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll().Include(tenant => tenant.Users);
    }
```

As you can see in this picture, the `Tenant` is available in the `Repository`.

Why can't I retrieve it? Am I overlooking the obvious mistake?

Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably GetAll() method does not include the entities in AddedState. Newly added tenant entity's state in object context will be "AddedState"

Comment: that's an answer :) i'll post a new question with a more specific question. thx!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you cannot call SaveChanges? Assuming that you are working in a transactional context, the changes aren't actually visible to any other transactions (modulo the isolation level that you use), so it should not actually have any impact on the correctness of your code. If you really can't call SaveChanges(), then you will need to change your repository implementation to explicitly look for objects in the 'Added' state. I have the code for this if you are interested.